# How to iterate through a grid algorithm

Tags: c#

I am looking for an algorithm that can iterate through a grid and transform it into another grid with the indexes in a new order.

Basically, given a grid of size n*m:

```
1_1 1_2 1_3 ... 1_n
2_1 2_2 2_3 ... 2_n
.
.
.
m_1 m_2 m_3 ... m_m
```

How could I transform it to:

```
1_1 1_2 1_4 ...
1_3 1_5 ...
1_6 ...
...
.
.
.
```

Assume, you iterate through the first grid, going left to right in the top row, then
left to right in the second row, all the way to, left to right in the bottom row.

Basically I pushing the elements into an upper triangle.

Another problem is how do I figure out the length and width of the grid used to store the triangle just by knowing what n and m is?
Is there a formula for that?

For example, a grid of 5*6, gets changed to 8*7...

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
```

becomes:

```
 1  2  4  7  11 16 22 29
 3  5  8  12 17 23 30
 6  9  13 18 24
 10 14 19 25
 15 20 26
 21 27
 28
```

Comment: if I wanted to find the x and y coordinate of 30 in the triangle, how would I get it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's define the "ordinal position" O(i,j) of each grid element (i,j) in a starting grid NxM, which is the function (i,j) -> i*N + j.

Now for the largest triangular number less than O(i,j), call it T == (k(k+1)/2 for some k, the new grid position for our (i,j) will be:
 (i,j) -> ( O(i,j) - T, k + T - O(i,j) )

---

Now substitute for O(i,j) and T to get:

(i,j) -> ( i*N + j - k(k+1)/2, k + (k+1)(k+2)/2 - i*N + j)

= ( i*N + j - k(k+1)/2, (k+1)(k+2)/2 - i*N + j)

---

That's as far as I can get it just now.

**Update:**
Note again that k is the side-length for the triangualr number T == k(k+1)/2.

Comment: Aargh! Does anyone know how to fix my mesed up formatting? All I did was indent, and I lose control over formatting.

Comment: Underlining text turns it into a heading.

Comment: If anyone knows a closed form for k that would complete the proof. @Matthew Strawbridge: I would say "Thank you" but that would just be stripped by some moderator or another. Mayhaps you will see ti before that happens.

Comment: I don't understand the formula, what is k?

Comment: k is the side-length of the triangle for the Triangular number T: "call it T == (k(k-1)/2 for some k".

Comment: Preceding formula should be T == k(k+1)/2 for some k.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work for me:

```
public static T[,] ConvertToUpperTriangle<T>(T[,] arr)
{
    // calculate the dimensions
    int elements = arr.GetLength(0) * arr.GetLength(1);

    double rows = 0.5 * (Math.Sqrt(8 * elements + 1) - 1);

    int newHeight = (int)rows;
    int newWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(rows);

    // create the new array
    var arr2 = new T[newHeight, newWidth];

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T element in arr)
    {
        arr2[j, i] = element;
        i--;
        j++;
        if (i < 0)
        {
            i = j;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    return arr2;
}
```

The `0.5 * (Math.Sqrt(8 * elements + 1) - 1)` comes from running `sum from 1 to n of n` and then `solve a = 0.5 * n * (n + 1) for n` through [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

**Edit:**

You can get the indices `i` and `j` for a given `index` as follows:

```
int rows = (int)(0.5 * (Math.Sqrt(8 * index + 1) - 1));

int bottomLeft = (int)(0.5 * rows * (rows + 1));
int difference = index - bottomLeft;

int i;
int j;

if (bottomLeft == index)
{
    i = 0;
    j = rows - 1;
}
else
{
    i = rows + 1 - difference;
    j = difference - 1;
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to find the x and y coordinate of the 30th element in the triangle, how would I get it?
the answer would be (6, 1), but I don't understand how to get it.

Comment: @omega: the 7th triangle number is 28 = 7*(7+1)/2. 30 - 28 = 2. The 8th diagonal will be the points (7,0), (6,1), ...